# Which design to chose for complex object initialization?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Lets say I have a class encapsulating one (or multiple) member(s) which must in some way be initialized and there is no reasonable way to use the class without it (so I don't want to make it optional).
Is it then better to have initialization run in its constructor like so:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    {
        if(!obj.initialize()
            throw ...;
    }

private:
    MyObject obj;
}
```

or would you suggest the following design:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    {
    }

    bool initialize()
    {
        return obj.initialize();
    }

private:
    MyObject obj;
}
```

The 1st one looks appealing because I can guarantee all requirements for using my class have been met after the constructor has run and I can report any errors by throwing an exception.

The 2nd looks good because it doesn't overload constructors with stuff that intuitively doesn't belong there, especially once the initialization routine gets complex and i.e. creates widgets, opens database connections, initializes 3rd party libraries etc. In a lot of legacy code I'm working with, ctors are flooded with parameters and intialization stuff, probably running thousands of code lines before this type of bloated object construction is even done. Trying to refactor these into something cleaner is really hard at some point because there are too many dependencies involved. That's what motivated my question.

The big disadvantage of design #2 I can see is that I need a public initialization routine which the client must remember to call. But since this can and probably will be forgotten, I have to track and check intialization state in all public members and somehow treat errors (probably an assert will do). This will also clutter my class with stuff that's not there if I chose design #1.

So what's my best choice here?

Comment: To me it sounds like you are contradicting yourself: "there is no reasonable way to use the class without it" and then " overload constructors with stuff that intuitively doesn't belong there". It is the job of the constructor to put the object in a consistent state, thus anything that is needed to do so should go to the constructor.

Comment: You don't have to have a bloated constructor. You can still organize your code properly into modules/functions and then call them from your constructor. You could have a hybrid solution where your `init` method is private and you call it from your constructor. That way you can throw if initialization fails.

Comment: You may create function to create each sub-object (So one line by sub-object).

Comment: Prefer throwing from constructors when you cannot establish the invariants of your class. That way you don't have to worry about invalid objects floating around. Otherwise create a factory that wraps the 2 steps (creation and initialization) together.

Comment: If `MyObject`'s constructor initializes itself, `MyClass` will not have to bother.

Comment: Where's the "complex"?

Comment: First one is the proper way to initialize a C++ class, but second one is more Objective-C. That's because C++ has a specific syntax when initializing, that means you had better to use them in order to refer what you are doing in your code to other developers. Also, C++ is a language that brings everything to you, you didn't mention any exception guarantee, class pattern, or else. For instance, it will change if your class is a singleton, using the shared getter member function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "The 1st one looks appealing because I can guarantee all requirements for using my class have been met after the constructor has run ...."

This **must** be the case otherwise the design is bad.

When the constructor completes then the *object* **must** be usable without any undefined behaviour and according to its interface specification.

**BUT** that does *not* mean the *object* needs to be *configured* for a given purpose.

I like to separate out *initialization* from *configuration*.

For example look at `std::fstream`. You can create a completely initialized *fstream object* without opening any files:

```
std::fstream fs; // initialized but not configured
```

It does not exhibit undefined behaviour and will operate according to its interface specification.

So you can use its interface to *configure* it to a given purpose - for example to read a specific file:

```
fs.open("myfile.txt", std::ios::in); // configured
```

The *default constructor* should do the *absolute minimum* to put the *object* into *working order* without, necessarily *configuring* it to a given task.

That being said there is no reason not to have *other* constructors to make creating *configured* objects easier:

```
std::fstream fs("myfile.txt", std::ios::in); // initialized & configured
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the code from `MyObject::initialize` to `MyObject`'s constructor (the `throw` as well, if necessary). Now the implicitly-defined default constructor for `MyClass` will do the right job.