# Best practice for deferred initialization of private class members

Tags: c++, constructor

Is there a best practice for deferred initialization of a private class member `M` of class `C`? For example:

```
class C {
public:
    C();

    // This works properly without m, and maybe called at any time,
    // even before startWork was called.
    someSimpleStuff();

    // Called single time, once param is known and work can be started.
    startWork(int param); 

    // Uses m. Called multiple times.
    // Guaranteed to only be called after startWork was called 
    doProcessing(); 

private:
    M m;
};

class M {
    M(int param);
};
```

Objects of class `C` can't be constructed because `M` doesn't have a default initializer.

If you can modify `M`'s implementation, it's possible to add an `init` method to `M`, and make its constructor accept no arguments, which would allow constructing objects of class `C`.

If not, you can wrap the `C`'s member `m` in `std::unique_ptr`, and construct it when it becomes possible.

However, both these solutions are prone to errors which would be caught in run-time. Is there some practice to make sure at **compile-time** that `m` is only used after its been initialized?

Restriction: An object of class C is handed to external code which makes use of its public interface, so C's public methods can't be split into multiple classes.

Comment: With a wrapper class using a uniqe_ptr and a get()-function you could make sure that it is not used without beeing initialized. However you can't make sure with this that your code does not try to do so, so you are still limited to runtime errors or default-parameters.

Comment: Why do you need to use deferred initialization? When are you planning to do it? Is `m` even needed to be a member? From your example code it looks like you are passing `param` every time you want to do some "work" in `C`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Clarified code example.

Comment: This may (or may not) be relevant here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338724/which-design-to-chose-for-complex-object-initialization/35339553#35339553

Answer (score 5):

The best practice is to never used deferred initialisation.

In your case, ditch the default constructor for `C` and replace it with `C(int param) : m(param){}`. That is, class members get initialised at the point of construction using base member initialisation.

Using deferred initialisation means your object is potentially in an undefined state, and achieving things like concurrency is harder.

Comment: @Danara Do you need `M` outisde of the function `startWork()`? If you don't then `M` local to `startWork()` and you could create it everytime you call `startWork()`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not always possible. e.g. The parameter is really only known at the time when startWork is called, but the object does exist before, and does have some limited public functionality. It's possible to refactor `m` into an inner class `D` of `C`, and have that inner class have a non-default constructor - but that doesn't solve the issue, it just proxies it to the `D` member of `C`.

Comment: @rozina Yes, I do. Modified example to emphasize that fact.

Comment: In which case, the extra functionality can be encapsulated in another class that receives on construction the object that already exists.

Comment: @Danra What happens when you call startWork() the second time? What will you do with M? Can you just create a new one and throw away the old one?

Comment: @rozina Yes you can.

Comment: @Bathsheba Unfortunately I am limited in that the same class must provide the entire interface, and that is beyond my control. (I am running a plug-in inside a host environment)

Comment: Lots of hitherto untold requirements coming out of the woodwork. But this is still not a showstopper. You can use virtual functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define ENABLE_THREAD_SAFETY

class C {
public:
    C();

    // This works properly without m, and maybe called at any time,
    // even before startWork was called.
    someSimpleStuff();

    // Called single time, once param is known and work can be started.
    startWork(int param); 

    // Uses m. Called multiple times.
    // Guaranteed to only be called after startWork was called 
    doProcessing(); 

    M* mptr()
    {
#ifdef ENABLE_THREAD_SAFETY
       std::call_once(create_m_once_flag, [&] {
          m = std::make_unique<M>(mparam);
       });
#else
        if (m == nullptr)
          m = std::make_unique<M>(mparam);
#endif
       return m.get();
    }
private:
    int mparam;
    std::unique_ptr<M> m;
#ifdef ENABLE_THREAD_SAFETY
    std::once_flag create_m_once_flag;
#endif
};

class M {
    M(int param);
};
```

Now all you have to do is stop using m directly, and access it through mptr() instead. It will only create the M class once, when it's first used.

Comment: What about thread safety? I doubt that this design is thread-safe.

Comment: @KingThrushbeard I have modified it and added (optional) thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with unique_ptr... Where do you see issues with that? When using M, you can easily check:

```
if(m)
    m->foo();
```

I know that this is not a compile-time check but as far as I know, there is no check possible with current compilers. Code analysis would have to be quite complicated to see something like this because you can initialize m whenever you are willing to in any method or - if public/protected - even in another file. A compile time check would mean that lazy initialization is done at compile time but the very concept of lazy initialization is runtime-based.

Comment: This is the clear drawback. If you need to have deferred initialization, though, I still think it is the best way. However, you cannot avoid this all the time.

Comment: Yes, but people add 'just an if' in a method, and do not realize that they have introduced a state and need to manage that in every bit of code. But of course, when deferred initialization, this is unavoidable. Just to stress that. +1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok from what I understand of your problem, would this be a solution?

You put the functionality that does not require `M` into `class D`. You create `D` object and use it. Once you need `M` and you want to do the `doProcessing()` code, you create object of `C`, pass `D` to it and initialize it with `param` that you now have.

The below code is made just to illustrate the idea. You probably don't need `startWork()` to be a separate function in this case and its code could be written in the constructor of `C`

Note: I have made all the functions empty, so I could compile the code to check for syntax errors :)

```
class M
{
public:
    M(int param) {}
};

class D
{
public:
    D() {}

    // This works properly without m, and maybe called at any time,
    // even before startWork was called.
    void someSimpleStuff() {}
};


class C
{
public:
    C(D& d, int param) : d(d), m(param) { startWork(param); }

    // Uses m. Called multiple times.
    // Guaranteed to only be called after startWork was called
    void doProcessing() {}

private:
    // Called single time, once param is known and work can be started.
    void startWork(int param) {}

    D& d;
    M m;
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.someSimpleStuff();

    C c(d, 1337);
    c.doProcessing();
    c.doProcessing();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make C constructible.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, because I am not the one actually calling C's methods - external code beyond my control is what expects an interface in a single class which has someSimpleStuff, startWork and doProcessing implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The question is "Is it possible to check at compile time that m is only used after it has been initialized without spliting the interface of C?"

The answer is **No**, you must use the type system to ensure that an object M is not used before initialized which would implies to split C interface. At compile time, compilers only know the type of objects, and the value of constant expressions. C cannot be a literal type. So you must use the type system: *you must split C interface to ensure at compile time that M is only used after initialization.*