# A member variable's initialization must be deferred. What is(are) the best design choice(s) for this class?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14

Suppose we have

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(A a, B b);
    //other member functions and variables
}

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
private:
    Foo foo;
    //other member variables
}
```

Ideally the member `foo` of `class Bar` should be initialized using the initialization lists. However if the initialization of `foo` depends on some operations in `Bar`'s constructor, initialization lists won't be an option. And since `foo` must be initialized before entering `Bar`'s constructor, what is(are) the best design choice(s) here?

I searched around and found a few options like having a `std::unique_ptr<Foo> pfoo;` ([Best practice for deferred initialization of private class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459021/best-practice-for-deferred-initialization-of-private-class-members)), but somehow the design seemed sloppy to me.

I want to avoid using raw pointers `Foo *` as possible.

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Anything I can use with a compiler that only supports up to C++14? :)

Comment: *"depends on some operations in Bar's constructor, initialization lists won't be an option."*. If you want to do it in constructor, then you can change your code to allow that.

Comment: You can call a function that returns a value in the initializer list. Sometimes this is a handy way to hoist a logical chunk of code from the constructor to let you initialize a member earlier.

Comment: "*foo depends on some operations in Bar's constructor*" and "*foo must be initialized before entering Bar's constructor*" seem to contradict each other.

Comment: @Rakete1111 That's the problem I'm trying to solve. "foo depends on some operations in Bar's constructor" is what I need. "foo must be initialized before entering Bar's constructor" is what must be done under the current design.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes but I'd like to know what are the best design choices here :)

Comment: I mean that choosing to defer initialization is already a decision which forbid more natural solution IMO. (as I present anyway).

Comment: If you can make your example code a little more concrete, could maybe try to better help. Another thing to keep in mind, is that you may simply want to make `Bar` default constructible. Usually in C++ you want classes to be movable, and a movable class generally has a default constructed state that can be accessed, regardless of whether you provide a default constructor.

Comment: You can make foo std::unique_ptr<Foo> - it will be empty pointer till you are ready to initialize it with std::make_unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace problematic:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar()
    {
        const Data& data = ComplexFunction();
        // How initialize foo ?
    }
private:
    Foo foo;
    //other member variables
};
```

by something like:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() : Bar(ComplexFunction()) {} // Delegate constructor

private:
    Bar(const Data& data) : foo(data.a, data.b) {}

private:
    Foo foo;
    //other member variables
};
```

If you want really defer construction of `Foo` (with a 2-steps initialization),
I would use `optional` (`boost` one if `std` one is not available for you (C++17)).